# How clear memoist cache?

Tags: ruby, memoization

How do you clear the temporary memory (cache) of [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist)  ?

Comment: Do you want to flush the whole cache for all objects, or for one object? I'm not sure the former is possible.

Comment: Did you see the ['Reload' section of the readme](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist#reload)?

Comment: i want to globally nuke